# Powershell: Filtering Properties Against properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have limited, self-taught experience with PowerShell so this is probably something basic but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm in Active Directory and I need to pull a list of users who's email address doesn't start with their SamAccountName.
(So if your login is jdoe but your email is johndoe@mycompany.com then your profile would be returned)

I've got most of what I need...but I can't figure out how to compare the two properties against eachother.

Right now I have

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties *| 
Where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false} | 
Select Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, PasswordNeverExpires
```

I've tried a few different things to filter what I need, the following command shows exactly what I want (but of course this syntax doesn't work)

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties *| 
Where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false} | 
Where-Object EmailAddress -Contains SamAccountName | 
Select Name, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, PasswordNeverExpires
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a scriptblock for the `Where-Object` filter like in your second pipeline element:

```
Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -notlike "$($_.SamAccountName)*" }
```

You can even combine it with the first filter, using the `-and` operator:

```
Where-Object { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -and $_.EmailAddress -notlike "$($_.SamAccountName)*" }
```

Finally, specify only the properties you need rather that `-Properties *` (no need to wait for the Domain Controller to return data you won't need):

```
$Properties = 'Name','SamAccountName','EmailAddress','PasswordNeverExpires'
Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -Properties $Properties |Where-Object {
    $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false -and 
    $_.EmailAddress -notlike "$($_.SamAccountName)*" 
} |Select-Object $Properties
```

Comment: You only need to specify properties that are not in the default property set. Since it pulls `Name` and `samAccountName` by default you only need to specify `EmailAddress` and `PasswordNeverExpires`. It will tack those properties onto the list of things it retrieves in addition to the default ones.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Correct, but I'm lazy, and by including them in the `$Properties` list, I can reuse the variable with `Select-Object` ;-)

Comment: Oh, yeah the -Properties * is just an artifact that I'll adjust before I finalize it and make the changes. Thanks! :)